# Sequentially/recursively replace the first numeric element of a column in a matrix with zero, until all = zero

Tags: r, recursion, matrix

I want to iteratively remove the first numeric elements, in all columns of a matrix, one iteration at a time, until all values=0. i.e.

```
matrix(nrow=3,ncol=2,Iteration1)
Iteration1=c(1,1,0,1,1,0)
Iteration2=c(0,1,0,0,1,0)
Iteration3=c(0,0,0,0,0,0)
```

The following function, based on a previous post, works to identify and replace the first numeric element. How can I cycle this result back into the function to remove the next numeric elements, and keep the results of each iteration?

## simulate data

```
data<-rbinom(20, size=1, prob=0.5)
data<-c(data)
dat<-matrix(data,nrow = 5,ncol=4)
mat<-dat

#identify first element=1

fun1<-function(mat){
cols<-c(1,2,3,4)
rown <-apply(mat[,cols] , 2, function(x) which(x==1)[1])
mat[cbind(rown,cols )] <- c(0,0,0,0)
return(mat)}

fun1(mat)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Why not create a matrix of zeros of required shape to begin with?

Comment: @EliKorvigo That's what I wondered as well. But he wants to keep the  results of each iteration, so this is probably not about the zero matrix, but about the others that are produced on the way.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you very much. The data is derived from sampling wild anmals and this process will be used in a power analysis to demonstrate the efficacy (or lack thereof) of the sampling method to those collecting it. I have to use the actual data because there are some who don't understand distributions. This will also enable the process to be run over other data sets. Thanks again.

Comment: If my answer was useful to you, please consider marking it as helpful by clicking on the checkmark next to it. This will indicate to other users that the answer was useful to you. Since you are new to SO, please have a look at the [tour] to understand how SO works.

Comment: I have selected the 'up' arrow next to your answer which changes to 'one' but does not save.

Comment: I note (!x==0) is useful to generalise fun1 for non-binomial data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems to be solved here. The first one is that your `fun1()` fails as soon as one of the columns does not contain any non-zero values. The second one is how to do the recursion and store the intermediate results. I will address both of them below.

### Improving fun1()

Your `fun1()` throws an error, as soon as one of the columns does not contain any non-zero values. The reason is that for these  columns, the value of `rown` is `NA`, which leads to an error in `mat[cbind(rown,cols )]`. The following version of `fun1()` does not have this issue (and is also more general as your function, because it  also works for matrices that have not 4 columns):

```
fun1 <- function(mat) {
  rows <- apply(mat, 2, function(x) which(x==1)[1])
  idx <- cbind(rows[!is.na(rows)], which(!is.na(rows)))
  mat[idx] <- 0
  return (mat)
}
```

### How to do the recursion

You can do the recursion with a while loop. At each step, the resulting matrix is  stored in a list:

```
mat <- dat
mats <- list()
while (any(mat != 0)) {
  mat <- fun1(mat)
  mats <- append(mats, list(mat))
}
```

`mats` is a list of four matrices, where the first one (`mats[[1]]`) is equal to `fun1(mat)` and the last one (`mats[[4]]`) contains only zeroes.